# XPath for overview values of emma report

Tags: xpath, emma

I generate EMMA reports during my build, they look like this

```
<report>
  <stats>
    <packages value="110"/>
    <classes value="1762"/>
    <methods value="12617"/>
    <srcfiles value="962"/>
    <srclines value="61320"/>
  </stats>
  <data>
    <all name="all classes">
      <coverage type="class, %" value="2%   (42/1762)"/>
      <coverage type="method, %" value="2%   (302/12617)"/>
      <coverage type="block, %" value="3%   (6849/258033)"/>
      <coverage type="line, %" value="3%   (1592.9/61320)"/>
```

I need to get the percentage from the value attributes of the /report/data/all/coverage nodes. Currently getting these:

```
Invalid XPath expression: "/report/data/all/coverage[starts-with(@type,'block')]@value": Unexpected '@'
Invalid XPath expression: "substring-before(/report/data/all/coverage[starts-with(@type,'block']@value,'%')": Expected: )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a forward slash from the XPath before the **@value** attribute. There is also a missing brackets in your **starts-with** function

Try the following

```
/report/data/all/coverage[starts-with(@type,'block')]/@value


substring-before(/report/data/all/coverage[starts-with(@type,'block')]/@value,'%')
```